# No device found (Nexus 5X with Android 7.1.2) in Android Studio 2.3.1 running under Ubuntu 16.04 Linux

Tags: android

After I have updated my Nexus 5X to Android 7.1.2, Android Studio is unable to see my device. I should mention that the device works fine (also for transfering files).
I should mention that this is happening only with Nexus 5x. I have also a Samsung S4 and there is no problem with it.
Running in terminal the following command:

```
>adb devices
```

I obtain the following message.

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I have to mention that everything went fine and the phone was recognized by adb when I used the previous version (Android 7.1.1) (also now the debug mode is activated on the phone).

I am using Android Studio 2.3.1.
I should mention that my operating system is Ubuntu 16.04[image]

Comment: From settings turn off `Usb debugging` and then turn on, then in dialog will appear, click `OK`.

Comment: No change. Still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several unsuccessful attempts, I have decided to give it one more try (from Linux terminal and not from the terminal window of Android Studio).
Switch to root and then run the following commands:

```
>adb kill-server
```

and then

```
>adb start-server
```

Which gave the following output:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

Afterwards I wrote:

```
adb devices
```

which gave as response:

```
List of devices attached 
01e0fbbdcccf32c9    unauthorized
```

And the screen of permission appeared on the Nexus 5X device, asking if I want to allow to debug.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 3):

You can just change USB connection to PTP or MTP. Works with my Nexus 5x device

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution works only when you are connecting to adb as a root. 
When I'm not a root I get `01e0fbbdcccf32c9    no permissions` instead of `01e0fbbdcccf32c9    unauthorized`

So I need to connect to 'adb' as a root, the solution for me was

```
$ sudo adb kill-server
$ sudo adb start-server
$ sudo adb devices
```

After doing these commands on the terminal, I get

```
List of devices attached 
01e0fbbdcccf32c9    unauthorized
```

and a **window of permissions will be opened on the phone.**